# mvc api core An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

Hi it get 3 days of my time but still alive,

This is my code in MVC core that consume an mvc API Core api project work fine when is in local and tested by postman

```
string Baseurl = "http://api.site.com";

    // GET: CustomerTypes
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<CustomerType> empInfo = new List<CustomerType>();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "3600");
            //Define request data format  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
            HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("/api/customerTypes");
            if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                var empResponse = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                empInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomerType>>(empResponse);

            }
            //returning the employee list to view  
            return View(empInfo);
        }
```

and this is configure in startup.cs in mvc api project

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                );
        });}

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        // app.UseCorsMiddleware();

        // Shows UseCors with named policy.
        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");



        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

And in control of API  set  [EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")] per control

I try many way:
1-  run api from local and call by remote web

2- publish api in remote and cal from local

3- call remote api by postman remote site

all of this not work and only when call local api by post man worked

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContent+d__49.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

For my Case, I Contact with host manager and they reset IIS and it work for me.